# How to do the navigations based on Gestures in windows phone apps?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, gesture-recognition

In my app I have a Home page and 2 other pages, So I want to navigate from one page to another and viceversa, When I'm horizontally swiping from right to left and when I'm horizontally swiping from left to right it should be navigated to Home page.

Suppose, We are on Home page on swiping from right to left( Home Page ---> Page1, again swipe ---> Page2, again swipe ---> Page1 ...Like that..... ) and on all the page if I swipe from left to right it should be navigated to Home page. How to do this in windows phone 8 app ?

My Code:

```
if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0) //when it is true it should navigate to next index value
            {
                try
                {

                    Pivot_Main.SelectedIndex++;// here every time it's showing the same index value it is not incrementing 
                    switch (Pivot_Main.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        Pivot_Main.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        txtBlock_Pivot_Heading.Text = "Temperature";
                        var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x8C, 0xC6, 0x3F));
                        b_celcius = true;
                        temperature_Page_Clear();
                        txtBlock_OptText.Text = "ºC";
                        btn_OptText.Content = "ºC";
                        Grid_PivotHeading.Background = brush;
                        Canvas_Home.Background = brush;
                        Canvas_DisplayName.Width = 55;
                        //   btn_OptText.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 380.0);
                        break;                  
                    case 1:
                        Pivot_Main.SelectedIndex = 1;
                        txtBlock_Pivot_Heading.Text = "Length";
                        length_Page_Clear();
                        b_meter = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please Help me, Genuine help is appreciated.

Comment: This is probably not the best solution but a Pivot control with blank headers can give you this effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here.

If you can manage to do things in one page then `Pivot` or `Panorama` controls will be sufficient.

Also,if you need that every page should be different and you want to use `NavigationService.Navigate()` to go from one page to another then, you have event called `Flick`.you can manage to handle left/right swipes through this through `HorizontalVelocity` and `VerticalVelocity` of that events.

To use Flick Gesture you will need to add this code in your xaml w.r.t. to your UI element:

```
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="OnFlick"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

and in .cs its handler:

```
    private void OnFlick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        // User flicked towards left
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
        {
         //your respective navigation to other page
        }
        // User flicked towards right
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
        {
        //your respective navigation to other page
        }
```

Details of Gesture support you can get [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967546%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: It works fine when i am swiping fast but if m swiping slowly on the page it is not responding correctly.

Comment: If you don't stop in between then it should recognize Flick events.anyway you also have drag events you can try them at last.